How to use a VBA Recordset in a SQL Query
I am trying to write a VBA function that returns a set of records that can be used in a SQL statement.
Here's what I tried:
Public Function GetYieldForContainer(code As String, fldName As String) As DAO.Recordset
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    Set db = CurrentDb
    
    sqlStr = "SELECT batch_id, yield as " & fldName & " FROM BatchYield WHERE container_id = " & code
    
    Set GetYieldForContainer = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
End Function

I then call it in a SQL statement as follows:
SELECT * FROM GetYieldForContainer("J", "jars");
Access displays the error "Syntax error in FROM clause." This is not very helpful; I'm guessing that there's a type mismatch, but I don't know what type I should use. Dos anybody know how to get this to work?
For context, I'm trying to write the VBA function because I need to do multiple LEFT JOINs of the resulting recordsets, and Access has very limited nesting capabilities in SQL.

If your container ID is a string it needs to be quoted ... where containerid = 'J'

"... and Access has very limited nesting capabilities in SQL" this sounds fishy. Why do you think this?

Both those queries can be run in single SQL statement. Access SQL does support subqueries and multiple LEFT JOINs. Please give it an earnest attempt and re-ask as needed.

Why are you using a variable to define an alias fieldname? That makes no sense. Provide sample data and desired output as formatted text tables.

Table and field names must be literal in Access SQL.
You could do something like this:
Public Function GetYieldForContainerSql(code As String, fldName As String) As String

    Dim strSQL As String
    
    sqlStr = "SELECT batch_id, yield as " & fldName & " FROM BatchYield WHERE container_id = '" & code & "'"
    
    GetYieldForContainerSql = sqlStr

End Function

and then build your final SQL:
code = "J"
fldName = "jars"

SQL = "SELECT * FROM (" & GetYieldForContainerSql(code, fldName) & ") As T"

and then apply this SQL to a query:
SomeQueryDef.SQL = SQL

which, in this case, can be reduced/shortcut to:
SomeQueryDef.SQL = GetYieldForContainerSql("J", "jars");


As I was writing a response and adding more detail so as to make my question clearer, I worked out a different solution to my problem. As topsail and Parfait pointed out, I was able to embed the SELECT query from my VBA function as an argument in a LEFT JOIN statement. The detail I had missed before was assigning an alias to the subquery result so that I could refer to fields in it. The result looks something like this:
SELECT Batch.*, jars, pouches
FROM (Batch LEFT JOIN 
        ((SELECT batch_id, yield AS jars FROM BatchYield WHERE container_id = GetContainerId("J")) AS JarYield)
            ON Batch.batch_id = JarYield.batch_id
    ) LEFT JOIN 
        ((SELECT batch_id, yield AS pouches FROM BatchYield WHERE container_id = GetContainerId("P")) AS PouchYield)
            ON Batch.batch_id = PouchYield.batch_id;

I have 7 container types, so the end query is going to be rather longer, but this lets me do it without having to have separate Access queries or VBA function calls for each SELECT query. I appreciate everyone's help in clarifying my thoughts and getting me to a solution.
